# Consider the following Matrix, are the conditions satisfied?

Tags: economics

I am trying to solve the following questions however i am having little lucky. I have searched online and consulted my textbook however neither are proving to be helpful. These types of questions always seem to come up in exams so i would be grateful for any help! I have attached the link to the questions below, many thanks!

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkins%E2%80%93Simon_condition).

Comment: Apologies for the edit, so the 3 principal minors have to be greater than 0?

Comment: Yes that´s true. I´ve posted an answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Much appreciated!

Comment: I restored the original title. Changing it to "Question solved" won't help anyone searching for help on this topic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$\textbf B=\textbf I-\textbf A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}0.1&0.5&0.2 \\ 0&0.1&0  \\ 0&0.2&0.2  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0.9&-0.5&-0.2 \\ 0&0.9&0  \\ 0&-0.2&0.8  \end{pmatrix}$$

Calculating the leading principal minors:

$|\textbf B_1| =|0.9|=0.9>0$

$|\textbf B_2|=\left|\begin{matrix}0.9&-0.5 \\ 0&0.9  \end{matrix}\right|=0.9\cdot 0.9-(0\cdot(-0.5))=0.81>0$

$|\textbf B_3|=\left|\begin{matrix}0.9&-0.5&-0.2 \\ 0&0.9&0  \\ 0&-0.2&0.8   \end{matrix}\right|=...$

If $|\textbf B_1|,|\textbf B_2|,|\textbf B_3| >0$, then the [Hawkins–Simon condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkins%E2%80%93Simon_condition) is fullfilled.